# meta property image not working in linkedin

Tags: html, metadata, share, linkedin-api, facebook-opengraph

meta property for image working fine in Facebook but not in LinkedIn 
I'm using

```
    <meta property="og:image" content='image url' />
```

I tried

```
<meta property="og:image:width" content="180" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="110" />
```

but still not working in Linkedin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
   <meta prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" property="og:title" content="{Your content}" />
    <meta prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" property="og:type" content="{Your content}" />
    <meta prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" property="og:image" content="{Your content}" />
    <meta prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" property="og:url" content="{Your content}" />
```

Forexample:

```
<meta prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" property="og:image" content="http://image.com/myimage.png" />
```

Or have a look at the code provided by Linkekedin:

```
<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head>
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/foo.jpg" />
</head>
<body>
```

> For the highest quality presentation on LinkedIn.com, the image
>   referenced in og:image should be at least 80 x 150px to prevent it
>   from being artificially stretched to fit the layout.